# User Email not working for local users

Tags: email, exchange, exchange-2003

I have a user that I needed to delete and then re-create her email account (Exchange 2003).  I haven't had issues doing this before but for some reason this time any user sending mail to her gets a bounce message saying the user email address doesn't exist.  However if I send mail to her from outside the network (different mail server) it works just fine.  Any Ideas?

Thanks!
msindle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have all of the other users delete the entry for the deleted user from their Outlook Autocomplete cache and recreate it by sending a new email to the deleted user.

Comment: I get the same message from a user that has never mailed to her before, however I can email her from the administrator account.